# How to enable logging on com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.ldap.LDAPRealm?

Tags: logging, glassfish, glassfish-3

I've just started working with GlassFish (3.1.1) and especially with configuring an LDAPRealm.

I have it kind of working, and I've started to look at the source code for the realm, and noted that there's a lot of calls to _Logger that I'd really like to be able to see, mainly for debugging my configuration.

Everything that I've seen seems to indicate that I should just need to add om.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.ldap.LDAPRealm to the Logger configuration in the admin webapp, and set the level, but even when I do that, and set the level to "FINEST", I don't see any logging for LDAPRealm.  I've also tried putting the higher level path, e.g., "com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.ldap" into the Logger configuration, but still don't see any logging from the LDAPRealm code.

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to enable this logging in GlassFish?

Thanks,
Jim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enable logging for `enterprise.system.core.security`. The Realm classes use the internal _logger, which itself refers to so-called `LogDomains`.

Inside `LogDomain.java` is the following:

```
public static final String   SECURITY_LOGGER = DOMAIN_ROOT + "enterprise.system.core.security";
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to add

```
-Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.debug=all
```

as JVM parameter in the Glassfish Admin Console...